# Efficiency of Gas Liquid Reactions Using Different Methods

Tags: reaction-control

I am looking to react MEA (monoethanolamine) with $\ce{CO_2}$. I was planning on doing this reaction by bubbling atmospheric air through water by using an air pump. I have researched that a smaller bubble size will lead to increased efficiency, but how efficient can this method get (like roughly how much of the $\ce{CO_2}$ will react with the MEA)?

Alternatively, I have also considered misting the MEA, then using a fan to blow air through the mist. I would think this method would be more efficient, because the fan can blow more air than the air can pump, and the particle size of the mist would be low. How efficient will this method be?

I would prefer to use the bubbling air through water method, but it depends on how much efficiency can be gained by using the mist/fan.

Comment: While CO2 slightly reacts, the process is called *absorption* of CO2. Using amines is standard, afaik, so you should be able to find plenty of data.

Comment: Perhaps use a very fine filter on the outlet for the CO2 gas...